# Is there a reason why 'unlist' transforms ordered factors into factors in R? (when the orderd factor is an element of a list)

Tags: r, list, factors

What is the reason  why this code  behaves as it does? It seems rather strange that a factor in a list is not ordered anymore when it is unlisted

```
of <- factor(1:3, ordered = TRUE)
ofl <- list(of)
is.ordered(unlist(ofl))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Actually, `unlist` does not remove the ordering. Check `unlist(of)`, nor `list`, it's unlisting the list.

Comment: well if the ordered factor is not in a list then unlist does nothing so this is not really surprising

Comment: adjusted the title of the question to clarify. Thank you